# Why are there a discrete set of solutions for period and length for a mass on a string moving in a circle?

Tags: centripetal-force

An object of mass m, suspended by a light inextensible string of length L that makes an angle of Ɵ with the vertical, moves in a horizontal circle with a frequency f and speed v. The tension in the string is T.

[image]

$$
v=2πrf\\
v^2/r=(4π^2 r^2 f^2)/r\\  
=4π^2 rf^2
$$

Centripetal force is provided by the horizontal component of the tension and the vertical component balances the weight so:

$$
F_c=(mv^2)/r = m4π^2 rf^2 = Tsin(θ)\\ 
mg=Tcos(θ)\\ 
tan⁡(θ)=(4π^2 rf^2)/g
$$

Substituting an expression for r in terms of L into this equation:

$$
r=Lsin(θ)\\
1/(cos⁡(θ))=(4π^2 Lf^2)/g\\ 
cos⁡(θ)=g/(4π^2 Lf^2 ) 
$$

This only seems to have a solution if $Lf^2>g/(4π^2 )$.

In the case where the period is 20s and the length is 10m for instance, there is no solution, however physically, this scenario is certainly possible.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the title, I didn't get what you mean by discrete set of solutions. There exist (or doesn't exist) only one solution. It's also curious that you think that the scenario violating your bound (in the setup you described) is certainly possible. I wonder based on what?

To understand inequality you've obtained you should think what happens when you approach that bound. $\cos\theta$ becomes closer and closer to $1$ and that correspond to very small $\theta$.

Let $x$ and $y$ be orthogonal axes in the horizontal plane. The circular motion in the horizontal plane may be represented as a harmonic oscillation in the $x$ axis and simultaneous harmonic oscillation in the $y$ axis with the same frequency $f$ but with the $\pi/2$ phase shift. I.e.
$$x=\cos\Big(2\pi f (t-t_0)\Big),\quad y=\sin\Big(2\pi f (t-t_0)\Big)$$

When you have a weight on the string oscillating with very small amplitude then it is known as a simple pendulum. It is well-know fact that a period of such simple pendullum doesn't depend on the amplitude and equals $T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$. But that's exactly the period that corresponds to your bound!

So this is the meaning of your bound - the slower the weight on the string rotates the closer this system is to the simple pendulum which can only have a certain period. That determines the minimal possible frequency in such a setup.